# JSTL c out does not print a scriptlet variable

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, scriptlet

In the following code snippet **c:out** is not working.

```
<%!
String myVariable="This is working";
%>
myVariable=='<c:out value="${myVariable}"/>'
myVariable=='<%= myVariable%>'
```

**Output**

> myVariable==''
>
> myVariable=='This is working'

The output in **c:out** tag coming as empty.Could you explain the reason for this?

Comment: Have you tried with myVariable=='<c:out value="Testing"/>'?

Comment: Yeah. I tried once more. And output is following.
 myVariable=='Testing'